# Why jQuery plugin is not applied when content of page is replaced with Ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Currently I am using jQuery ajax to add content to the page and I am using jquery.selectbox-0.6.1.js plugin to style selectbox.

Plugin gets applied when first time I load the page but when I click to get ajax response to replace some contents of page then selectbox plugin does not applies css style to replaced ajax select box.

Here is my code :

```
$.ajax({
                  url: '/find-job?filter=1',
                  type:'GET',
                  async:'false',
                  success: function (data) 
        {
                      var $response=$(data);
                      $response.find('.view').each(function(){
                      $('.view').replaceWith(this).html;
           });
         }

});
```

Everything works fine but selectbox plugin is not applied to select box.

Why plugin is not automatically applying css ?

Comment: The plugin needs to be reinitialized on new added element if no delegating method is supported. BTW, this looks strange `$('.view').load(this).html`

Comment: Yes but how I can reinitialize it ?

Comment: How do you initialize it the first time?! Then recall it in success callback

Comment: In your callback you have to do the same as in your onload: something like $("select").selectbox();

Answer (score 0):

you can reinitialize the selectbox plugin by putting it into success callback, after adding the new content:

```
success: function (data) {
    var $response=$(data);
    $response.find('.view').each(function(){
        $('.view').replaceWith(this).html();
    });
    $("#element").selectbox();
});
```

actually your code is a mess, but you get the idea.